# Splunk - "Not Found" from cli when connecting to remote server

Tags: command-line-interface, splunk

Trying to run a remote command/search via the cli, but getting "Not Found"

`allowRemoteLogin=always` is already set in `server.conf`

The management port is set to 8081.

```
/opt/splunk/bin/splunk show splunkd-port -auth 'admin:XXXXXXXX' -uri 'https://XXXXXXXXX:8081'
Not Found
```

When run remotely (on the server with Splunk running) it's fine:

```
/opt/splunk/bin/splunk show splunkd-port -auth 'admin:XXXXXXXXXXXX'
Splunkd port: 8089
```

I am running Splunk behind Nginx, but with the URI command line option I am using the IP, not the fully qualified domain name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the command on the Splunk server it says the management port is 8089.  Therefore, you should use that port in your remote command.

`/opt/splunk/bin/splunk show splunkd-port -auth 'admin:XXXXXXXX' -uri 'https://XXXXXXXXX:8089'

Comment: I am a remarkable dumbass. I completely missed that. Thanks for pointing that out!